# button will not execute click function in google apps script html service

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I've spent 2 days trying to figure this out so any help is appreciated.

I was following this [nice little video tutorial series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRQvySxaCW0&list=PLv9Pf9aNgemt82hBENyneRyHnD-zORB3l&index=1)
and I wanted to try something basic before getting any further: get an html button to show a javascript alert using google apps script and their HTML Service component, but for the life of me, I can't understand why the alert is not triggered.

Here's my code

Index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
              <script>
                 document.getElementById("btnSearch")
                         .addEventListener("click",showAlert);                
              function showAlert() {
                alert("hello world");
              }
              </script>
          </head>
          <body>
            <div>
              <label>Enter code</label>
              <input type="text" id="txtStudentID"/>
              <button id="btnSearch">Search</button>
            </div>
          </body>
        </html>
```

and my 
code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}
```

I also try it like google shows it [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#user_objects): but I still don't get the alert to trigger after the button is pressed:

```
<input type="button" value="Search"
      onclick="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(showAlert)
          .withUserObject(this)" />
```

it's like anything that starts with "document.getElementByID..." within the script tags will simply not work

What am I missing? is this something not longer supported with GAPS? is there a different/proper way to get this to work?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> anything that starts with "document.getElementByID..." within the script tags will simply not work

Yes. Because at the time script tags are  evaluated, there's no element with id `btnSearch`.

#### Solution(s):

- Move the script to the bottom of DOM.

```
<div>
  <label>Enter code</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtStudentID" />
  <button id="btnSearch">Search</button>
</div>

<script>
  function showAlert() {
    alert('hello world');
  }
  document.getElementById('btnSearch').addEventListener('click', showAlert);
</script>
```

- Alternatively, As the previous answer states, use the `load` trigger; so that the script is evaluated after the DOM is loaded.

```
<script>
  function showAlert() {
    alert('hello world');
  }
  function load1() {
    document.getElementById('btnSearch').addEventListener('click', showAlert);
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', load1);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much man.. I know it had to be something small that I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting addEvent into window.onload